# Modelling Fluid-Solid Interaction using SPH

Tags: dynamic, simulation, particle-system

I am a newbie here, so I apologize if my question seems weird. This is about my SPH simulator, which not be able to handle fluid-solid interaction yet. My simulator can simulate fluid well, but I got confused when I want to add a solid object during the simulation.

I've read many paper, and I got several conclusion in my mind, please correct me if I'm wrong,

1. Both of solid and fluid object are modeled with single particle
   system, which each object particle has own parameter value, like
   mass, mass density, artificial viscosity, etc.
2. In each time step, SPH loop procedure is computed as usual in both of object, means
   that each particle object can contribute to another particle object
   if they are in radius of h, regardless what kind is that particle.
3. The difference with system that contains only fluid particles, is in
   fluid-solid system, exists Elastic Force that computed only between
   solid object. This force is not computed for fluid particle.

That is. At last, the questions.

What about SPH specific parameters like smoothing length, radius of particle, etc? Are these different between solid and fluid when computing forces for each particle?
What actually correct way when calculating forces for both kind of particle? Is it just compute it in single looping?

The papers I've read tells me the formula, but I think I need the basic idea first.

Thanks.

Comment: The tag seems out of place, or do you indeed expect some c++ specific answer to this?